# How to diagnose why an update cannot be installed on Windows Server 2003?

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-update

On one specific server sometimes I get an error message when I'm trying to install security updates. The message is showed immediately after trying to install them. Where can I find the log files which show what's causing the problem?

**Update:** Here are some details from the WindowsUpdate.log, the first relevant line in the log is:

```
... Agent WARNING: LoadLibrary failed for srclient.dll with hr:8007007e
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming it's just some, and not all... then you'll need to post an error number/message to get some information.

If it's all, then try re-registering the windows installer service

```
msiexec /unregister
msiexec /regserver
```

For **Agent WARNING: LoadLibrary failed for srclient.dll with hr:8007007e** - have a look at [KB831429](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/831429)

Comment: Hm, I tried to install them one by one. The problem seems to be just the malware removal update (April 2009).

Comment: Seems a problem with some system files. I guess this server needs further inspection. There seem to be some issues with the RAID controller. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at %systemroot%\windowsupdate.log

You can also check Event Viewer.

Microsoft's general troubleshooting guide for updates can be found [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/906602).

Answer (score 1):

Remember also [for XP and before, see below]that each individual update has its own log file in the Windows directory.  This will be, usually, named KBnnnnnn.log where n is the update number.  The update failure will usually be in the Event Log but the details will be in that log file.

Vista and 2008 have changed this logging but I don't remember the details.  I'll edit it again if I find it.

Also, for anyone watching the progress bar in Windows Update stalling, this phenomenon is unfortunately normal for some updates;  the Malware Removal Tool actually scans your directories (which would uncover the RAID problems the original poster had.)  Exchange updates like to take their time as well as they stop and start all the services as they run.